# Login screen using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

Can anyone help how to design login screen using Bootstrap in .NET MVC4 Application?
 The login page must work well with all browsers.

```html
<div id="loginForm" style="width: 1189px; height: 705px; vertical-align: central;">
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div style="padding-top: 200px; text-align: center;">

        <h2 style="color: #991f3d;">Heading</h2>
        <table style="vertical-align: central; width: 400px; border: groove">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr style="padding-top: 10px">
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { style = "width:200px", @maxlength = "100" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { style = "width:200px", @maxlength = "20" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="button" style="background-color: #991f3d; text-align: center; border: double" /></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Integrating Bootstrap could be as simple as adding some classes to your `<input>` elements. What are you actually asking?

Comment: yeah... ok.. need  to add class..